# Spark (Scala): Compute session length of user in DataFrame with continuous active hours

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I like to do the following transformation. Given a data frame that records whether a user is active each hour, and a continuous # of hours that user is active is counted as session, I'm trying to gather the cumulative hour in each session.

For instance, the original DataFrame would look like the following:

```
scala> val df = sc.parallelize(List(
  ("user1",0,true),
  ("user1",1,true),
  ("user1",2,false),
  ("user1",3,true),
  ("user1",4,false),
  ("user1",5,false),
  ("user1",6,true),
  ("user1",7,true),
  ("user1",8,true)
)).toDF("user_id","hour_of_day","is_active")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [user_id: string, hour_of_day: int, is_active: boolean]

  +-------+-----------+---------+
  |user_id|hour_of_day|is_active|
  +-------+-----------+---------+
  |user1  |0          |true     |
  |user1  |1          |true     |
  |user1  |2          |false    |
  |user1  |3          |true     |
  |user1  |4          |false    |
  |user1  |5          |false    |
  |user1  |6          |true     |
  |user1  |7          |true     |
  |user1  |8          |true     |
  +-------+-----------+---------+
```

And I'd like to add two columns that tracks when a session begin and the length of the session. Getting one of these columns would allow me to solve the other so either would work.

Example below:

```
  +-------+-----------+---------+------------------+--------------+
  |user_id|hour_of_day|is_active|session_begin_hour|session_length|
  +-------+-----------+---------+------------------+--------------+
  |user1  |0          |true     |0                 |1             |
  |user1  |1          |true     |0                 |2             |
  |user1  |2          |false    |null              |0             |
  |user1  |3          |true     |3                 |1             |
  |user1  |4          |false    |null              |0             |
  |user1  |5          |false    |null              |0             |
  |user1  |6          |true     |6                 |1             |
  |user1  |7          |true     |6                 |2             |
  |user1  |8          |true     |6                 |3             |
  +-------+-----------+---------+------------------+--------------+
```

I tried to use WindowSpec to look back a row but that wouldn't allow me to compute the value for column based on the last row, if that column doesn't exist in the original DF.

Are there any elegant solution to solve this problem, preferably in Scala.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's identify if given record marks the beginning of the session:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val userWindow = Window.partitionBy($"user_id").orderBy($"hour_of_day")
val prevActive = lag($"is_active", 1).over(userWindow) 
val newSession = $"is_active" && (prevActive.isNull || not(prevActive))

val withInd = df.withColumn("new_session", newSession)

// +-------+-----------+---------+-----------+   
// |user_id|hour_of_day|is_active|new_session|
// +-------+-----------+---------+-----------+
// |  user1|          0|     true|       true|
// |  user1|          1|     true|      false|
// |  user1|          2|    false|      false|
// |  user1|          3|     true|       true|
// |  user1|          4|    false|      false|
// |  user1|          5|    false|      false|
// |  user1|          6|     true|       true|
// |  user1|          7|     true|      false|
// |  user1|          8|     true|      false|
// +-------+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

Next let's generate session id:

```
val session = when(
  $"is_active",
  sum($"new_session".cast("long")).over(userWindow)
)

val withSession = withInd.withColumn("session", session)

// +-------+-----------+---------+-----------+-------+
// |user_id|hour_of_day|is_active|new_session|session|
// +-------+-----------+---------+-----------+-------+
// |  user1|          0|     true|       true|      1|
// |  user1|          1|     true|      false|      1|
// |  user1|          2|    false|      false|   null|
// |  user1|          3|     true|       true|      2|
// |  user1|          4|    false|      false|   null|
// |  user1|          5|    false|      false|   null|
// |  user1|          6|     true|       true|      3|
// |  user1|          7|     true|      false|      3|
// |  user1|          8|     true|      false|      3|
// +-------+-----------+---------+-----------+-------+
```

Finally let's create a new window and compute values of interest:

```
val userSessionWindow = userWindow.partitionBy($"user_id", $"session")

val sessionBeginHour = when(
  $"is_active",
  min($"hour_of_day").over(userSessionWindow)
)

val sessionLength = when(
  $"is_active",
  $"hour_of_day" + 1 - sessionBeginHour
).otherwise(0)

val result = withSession
  .withColumn("session_begin_hour", sessionBeginHour)
  .withColumn("session_length", sessionLength)
  .drop("new_session")
  .drop("session")

result.orderBy($"hour_of_day").show
// +-------+-----------+---------+------------------+--------------+
// |user_id|hour_of_day|is_active|session_begin_hour|session_length|
// +-------+-----------+---------+------------------+--------------+
// |  user1|          0|     true|                 0|             1|
// |  user1|          1|     true|                 0|             2|
// |  user1|          2|    false|              null|             0|
// |  user1|          3|     true|                 3|             1|
// |  user1|          4|    false|              null|             0|
// |  user1|          5|    false|              null|             0|
// |  user1|          6|     true|                 6|             1|
// |  user1|          7|     true|                 6|             2|
// |  user1|          8|     true|                 6|             3|
// +-------+-----------+---------+------------------+--------------+
```